# Ajuda com nested loop

Tags: python, loop

**yhat_tr** é uma coluna de 500 itens.

**d_tr**, tb com 500 elementos, é outra coluna, que carreguei em separado da primeira, são fontes diferentes, mas com os mesmos índices.
 Meu código é esse:

```
TP, FP, TN, FN = 0,0,0,0
    print(len(yhat_tr))
    print(len(d_tr))


    for i in yhat_tr:
      for a in d_tr: # d_tr = coluna do excel com as classes 1 ou -1
        if i > 0 and a > 0:
          TP += 1

        if i > 0 and a < 0:
          FP += 1

        if i < 0 and a < 0:
          TN += 1

        if i < 0 and a > 0:
          FN += 1

    print ('Totais:', '\nTP: ', TP, '\nFP: ', FP, '\nTN: ', TN, '\nFN: ', FN)

    # Cálculo da Acurácia
    accuracy = (TP + TN) / (TP + FP + TN + FN)
    print ('Acurácia (ACC): ', accuracy)
```

Estou achando que está errado este loop porque de 1000 dados estou com resultados somando
TP:  63000 
FP:  63000 
TN:  62000 
FN:  62000, ou seja, tem que estar somando mais de uma vez cada item. Era para TP, Tn, FP, FN darem o total de 1000.

Minha tentativa era de:
Percorre a linha 1: se o valor do iten de índice 0 de y_hat > 0 e o mesmo indice de dr_tr > 0, soma 1 em TP (um contador)
A mesma lógica nas demais variáveis, alternando o sinal <, >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for i in yhat_tr:
      for a in d_tr:
```

Com essas duas linhas você está iterando 500*500 vezes. Para cada valor de i você itera 500 valores de a.

O que você precisa é algo do tipo

```
for i, a in zip(yhat_tr, d_tr):
```

Comment: Perfeito!
Te amo.

Comment: Marca comp correto, de nada :)